# Not noticing any performance improvement when using async

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I have a small program that executes the aws s3 cli commands but with different arguments. I'm using the `Command` crate and the the command makes a network call and returns some response. At first I have this synchronous & single-threaded implementation:

```
fn make_call<'a>(_name: &'a str, _bucket_poll: &mut BucketPoll<'a>) -> Option<BucketDetails<'a>> {
    let invoke_result = invoke_network_call(_name);
    let mut bucket = BucketDetails::new(_name);
    match invoke_result {
        Ok(invoke_str) => {
            bucket.output = invoke_str;
            _bucket_poll.insert_bucket(bucket.clone());
            _bucket_poll.successful_count += 1;
            Some(bucket)
        }
        Err(_) => {
            _bucket_poll.insert_bucket(bucket);
            None
        }
    }
}
// I invoke this function in sequential order, something like
make_call('name_1');
make_call('name_2');
make_call('name_3');
```

Because I don't really care at which order this function is executed, I decided to learn `Tokio` to help with performance. I changed the `make_call` function to be async:

```
async fn make_call_race() -> ExecutionResult {
    let bucket_poll = BucketPoll::new();
    let bucket_poll_guard = Arc::new(Mutex::new(bucket_poll));
    loop {
        let bucket_details = tokio::select! {
            Some(bucket_details) = make_call_async("name_1", &bucket_poll_guard) => bucket_details,
            Some(bucket_details) = make_call_async("name_2", &bucket_poll_guard) => bucket_details,
            Some(bucket_details) = make_call_async("name_3", &bucket_poll_guard) => bucket_details,
            Some(bucket_details) = make_call_async("name_4", &bucket_poll_guard) => bucket_details,
            else => { break }
        };
        success_printer(bucket_details);
    }
    // more printing, no more network calls
    ExecutionResult::Success
}
```

`make_call_async` is essentially the same as `make_call`:

```
async fn make_call_async<'a>(
    _name: &'a str,
    _bucket_poll_guard: &'a Arc<Mutex<BucketPoll<'a>>>,
) -> Option<BucketDetails<'a>> {
    {
        if let Ok(bucket_poll_guard) = _bucket_poll_guard.lock() {
            if bucket_poll_guard.has_polled(_name) {
                return None;
            }
        }
    }
    let invoke_result = invoke_network_call(_name);
    let mut bucket = BucketDetails::new(_name);
    match invoke_result {
        Ok(invoke_str) => {
            bucket.output = invoke_str;
            {
                if let Ok(mut bucket_poll_guard) = _bucket_poll_guard.lock() {
                    bucket_poll_guard.insert_bucket(bucket.clone());
                    bucket_poll_guard.successful_count += 1;
                }
            }
            Some(bucket)
        }
        Err(_) => {
            {
                if let Ok(mut bucket_poll_guard) = _bucket_poll_guard.lock() {
                    bucket_poll_guard.insert_bucket(bucket);
                }
            }
            None
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the async version, I do see that my network calls are made a random order but I do not notice any speedups. I increased the number of network calls to ~50ish invocations but the runtime is nearly the same if not slightly worse. As I am new to async programming and Rust in general, I would like to understand why my async implementation does not seem to offer any improvement.

Extra:

Here is the `invoke_network_call` method:

```
fn invoke_network_call(_name: &str) -> core::result::Result<String, AwsCliError> {
    let output = Command::new("aws")
        .arg("s3")
        .arg("ls")
        .arg(_name)
        .output()
        .expect("Could not list s3 objects");
    if !output.status.success() {
        err_printer(format!("Failed to list s3 objects for bucket {}.", _name));
        return Err(AwsCliError);
    }
    let output_str = get_stdout_string_from_output(&output);
    Ok(output_str)
}
```

EDIT: yorodm's comment makes sense. What I did was use Tokio's Command instead of std::process's Command and made the invoke_network_call async. This reduced my runtime by half. Thank you!

Comment: Your `invoke_network_call` function is sync, and blocks the executor until the `aws` command invocation finishes

Comment: right, so would the solution be tacking on async to the invoke_network_call function?

Comment: Async is not about performance improvement per se. Any improvement would come from doing tasks in parallel instead of in sequence. Async isn't "the fast version" of network calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite `invoke_network_call` using an [async version of Command](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.8.0/tokio/process/struct.Command.html).

```rust
async fn invoke_network_call(_name: &str) -> core::result::Result<String, AwsCliError> {
    let output = tokio::process::Command::new("aws")
        .arg("s3")
        .arg("ls")
        .arg(_name)
        .output()
        .await
        .expect("Could not list s3 objects");
    if !output.status.success() {
        err_printer(format!("Failed to list s3 objects for bucket {}.", _name));
        return Err(AwsCliError);
    }
    let output_str = get_stdout_string_from_output(&output);
    Ok(output_str)
}
```

Thus removing the blocking `std::process::Command` call. However I would say that if you're going to access AWS services [you should go with rusoto](https://crates.io/crates/rusoto)